# Android Fragment strange behaviour

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have main activity with list of fragments to dynamically add/delete them. When I create new fragment and put it to my list, `onAttach()` ,`onCreate()`, `onCreateView()` methods are called. But if I remove this fragment from list and then create new one, this methods are not called. Can anyone explain me why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your fragments might be existing in the Stack even though u r removing them,so have a look at your backStack

Comment: No clear way to answer this without your sample code.